# How to fix "EntityMemberChanged was called without first calling EntityMemberChanging"

Tags: entity-framework

This came up time and again for us. After reading such a message, there's nothing intuitive to do and debug.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What this poorly-documented error is trying to say is that you accidentally set up a system in which *tracking changes* causes *more changes*.

When Entity Framework changed a property on one of your entities, such as during SaveChanges with identity ID updates, **you ran code that changed other tracked properties**.

For example, the property that Entity Framework was setting triggered an event, perhaps `INotifyPropertyChanged`, which perhaps was subscribed to by a `BindingSource` or some binding list, whose `ListChanged` event handler was in the UI and triggered a calculation of some other property, and the change tracker detected the second property change.

**The simple diagnosis** is to place a breakpoint on the SaveChanges() call and immediately after the SaveChanges call(). When the first breakpoint is hit, place a breakpoint on each event handler that could possibly be triggered. (`BindingSources` are notorious for multiplying each other's events.) Continue debugging. If any breakpoint is hit other than the point immediately following SaveChanges, you know where the problem is.

**The simple solution** is to set a flag, such as `IsSaving`, on each side of the SaveChanges call. Then in each misbehaving event handler, do a simple check and do not modify any entities if the DbContext is in the process of saving. Make sure you use `finally` in case SaveChanges throws an exception that you catch at a higher level:

```
IsSaving = true;
try
{
    await db.SaveChangesAsync()
}
finally
{
    IsSaving = false;
}
```

(One other possibility is that you were changing the entity from multiple threads — *never* involve the change tracker in multiple threads!)

Comment: Thank you for posting both the question and such a detailed answer!

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same issue. I had wired to the INotifyPropertyChanged event that created the possibility for a property to change during the SaveChanges() call.  I think it is a better practice to unwire the event handlers of you tracked entities when performing dbContext.SaveChanges(), Remove().

Comment: Unwiring would often be the safest and lightest alternative. However, for us there is a case where it is valuable to be notified of the change even though we are not setting Entity Framework-visible properties during that time.

Answer (score 3):

I'll explain my experience with this error, hoping it might help someone. And thanks to [jnm2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/521757/jnm2) for beautiful explanation.

I had **Invoice** and **Receipt** entities, and **InvoiceViewModel**.
Thie ViewModel was subscribed to Invoice property changed, inside which it was raising **CanExecuteChanged** events.

I added Receipt to Invoice navigation property and called SaveChanges(), which raised **Invoice.ReceiptID** property changed and triggered OnPropertyChanged event handler on the ViewModel, which in turn raised all kinds of CanExecuteChanged events.

**The problem** was that one of the Can*CommandName*Execute methods was calling **Context.ChangeTracker.HasChanges()** which ultimately threw an exception.

**How I fixed it?**
I followed jnm2, I flagged VM with IsSaving and checked for the flag inside OnPropertyChanged event handler.

Once again, thanks jnm2, and hope someone finds this helpful as well.